# Python: Why wont the if statement detect whether the variables are greater or less than 80?

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

```
print("=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=")
print("")
height = float(input("Input the height (cm): "))
width = float(input("Input the width (cm): "))
length = float(input("Input the length (cm): "))
print("")
print("=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=")


if height or width or length > 80:
    print("Rejected, measurements exceed 80cm.")
elif height or width or length < 80:
    print("Works")
else:
    print("Error")
```

It prints the rejected message when I enter numbers lower than 80 and larger than 80. Anyone see what im missing?

Comment: `if height or width or length > 80:` doesn't work as you expect. This is evaluated as : `if (height) or (width) or (length > 80):`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height or width or length > 80` is evaluated as `(height) or (width) or (length > 80)`. Any float will be considered truthy in this context if it is different from 0, and the evaluation will stop as soon as Python can be sure of the outcome.

So, in your case, if `height` isn't zero, the expression will be considered `True`.

You should use:

```
if height > 80 or width > 80 or length > 80:
```

or:

```
if any(dimension > 80 for dimension in (height, width, length)):
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
if height > 80 or width > 80 or length > 80:
    print("Rejected, measurements exceed 80cm.")
```

The statement `if height` (without the comparison part)  will return `true` if `height != 0`